# Why isn't the SECURITY_UNAUTHORIZED_VIEW config option redirecting me when I use the roles_required decorator?

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

When I use the @roles_required decorator and don't have the required role, I'm not being redirected to the set page. In fact I'm not being redirected at all but when I manually logout and get redirected to /login it displays all the error messages I should have received.

Here's what I do to get that behavior:

1. login as user@dummy.net on /login (role = end-user)
2. Flask-Security redirects me to the homepage ('/')
3. I'm trying to access /authtest which has the @roles_required('admin') decorator.
4. Nothing happens, I stay on the homepage.
5. I logout via /logout and am redirected to /login
6. The login pages show me the messages:

   - You do not have permission to view this resource.
   - Please log in to access this page.

The first of the two messages is probably in reply to my attempt at going to /authtest, the second one is because the /logout redirects me to the homepage which in turn redirects me to /login because of the /login_required decorator.
What I don't understand is why the no permission message isn't displayed in step 4 on the homepage.

The code is mostly taken from the flask-security quickstart example:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, \
    UserMixin, RoleMixin, login_required, roles_required

# Create app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'super-secret'
app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'] = 'super-secret-salt'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///mdb.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SECURITY_UNAUTHORIZED_VIEW'] = '/redir'

# Create database connection object
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Define models
roles_users = db.Table('roles_users',
        db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
        db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id')))

class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

# Setup Flask-Security
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)

# Create some testusers
@app.before_first_request
def create_user():
    db.create_all()
    # Create the Roles "admin" and "end-user" -- unless they already exist
    user_datastore.find_or_create_role(name='admin', description='Administrator')
    user_datastore.find_or_create_role(name='end-user', description='End user')
    # Create some default users if they don't exist already
    if not user_datastore.get_user('admin@dummy.net'):
        user_datastore.create_user(email='admin@dummy.net', password='pass')
    if not user_datastore.get_user('user@dummy.net'):
        user_datastore.create_user(email='user@dummy.net', password='pass')
    # Commit any database changes; the User and Roles must exist before we can add a Role to the User
    db.session.commit()
    # Assign the admin role to the created user
    user_datastore.add_role_to_user('admin@dummy.net', 'admin')
    user_datastore.add_role_to_user('user@dummy.net', 'end-user')
    db.session.commit()

# Views
@app.route('/')
@login_required
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/authtest')
@roles_required('admin')
def authtest():
    return render_template('authtest.html')

@app.route('/redir')
def redir():
    return render_template('redir.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in flask-security see:
https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/issues/677
This PR to fix it was never merged:
https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/pull/726

This has been fixed in my maintained fork available at:
https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Security-Too/

The only workaround I can offer is to define your own security.unauthorized_callback and perform the redirection there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however even using your version (3.2.0) of flask-security-too doesn't change the described behavior for me. I double checked that I'm actually using your fork instead of the original and I do. Maybe I made another mistake somewhere in the code and fixing the other bug just got rid of one of the issues?

Comment: Sorry - yes - you need to set UNAUTHORIZED_VIEW="redir" - it is  a view name (as in the function name) not a url.

Comment: Alright, so this works to redirect me. However, I'm **still** getting the error messages at /login (step 6). I managed to workaround this by using
if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/login')
instead of @login_required
but I wonder if I'm still doing something wrong of if that's just a bug with flask-security (and flask-security-too) that I'll have to live with.

Comment: Could you add your *.html - in particular your authtest.html? Flashing required each template to explicitly call get_flashed_messages() - in order to retrieve and pop them from the session. Otherwise they will stay in the session until a template does that.